# How can I create a link in orientdb studio?

Tags: orientdb

In this [link](http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/OrientDB_Studio#Create_a_new_record) there is a very basic example.

I have a class, its name is "dog" and it has a "name" property and a "childs" property. The "childs" property type is LINKLIST.

When a try to create a new dog object I crete a "childs" field but I don't know how to fill it.

Please point me to a more complete tutorial (actualy I search it with out success).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the query for that:

```
insert into animal set name = 'dog', children = [<rid>]
```

where `<rid>` is the record id of the child.

Comment: the final query insert into dog set name = 'dog8', childs = [#6:0]

Comment: I read somewhere in the internet that you need help to improve documentation, and I want to help, just point me in the right way.

Comment: Hey Delta, this is the entrypoint of documentation: http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/Main. In what area do you like to contribute? Tutorial? Reference Guide?

Comment: Hi Lvca, I'm a python/java-scrip developer, and I want to write  tutorials to integrate orientdb with that. What is next?

Comment: You could help us to improve the Studio. It's 100% HTML, jQuery and JS that talks with OrientDB using the HTTP REST protocol via Ajax. WDYT?

Comment: OrientDB Studio: tab database, make it working the alter of class and properties via the visual table by enabling checkbox, etc. All you should to run are commands like "alter class XX superclass YY", etc.

Comment: I'll work on this on the weekend and report to you in your google code site.

Comment: So far I enable the click event to start the row edition, I'll get this done tomorrow. How can I send you the changes.